# Reading files in directory in sorted order Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have a folder in which I have files like 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ... 40.jpg;

```
root_dir = r'C:\Users\ab\pythonfiles\Compressed_images'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file in files:
        print(file, '\n')
```

It prints this

```
1.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
...
19.jpg
2.jpg
20.jpg
...
```

I want it to read in the order 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, ... ; how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sorting the files list using `sorted`.

**Ex:**

```
root_dir = r'C:\Users\ab\pythonfiles\Compressed_images'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file in sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0])):
        print('For file: \n', file)
```